# Trying to convert decimal to decimal in DB2

Tags: sql, casting, db2, db2-400

I have 25.555, I'm trying to convert to 25.555000.

I used `CAST(25.555 AS DEC(9,6))`, but I'm getting the result as 25.554999.

Note: Some are working fine( ex: 16.667 to 16.667000) but not all.

1. The first integer is the total number of digits, it may range from 1 to 3.
2. The second integer is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, it may range from 0 to 6.

Comment: I get 25.555000, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=5b80b6a478368fa174da8febb873b26d

Comment: Which Db2? luw, z, I?

On db2 luw I get:

$ db2 "select CAST(25.555 AS DEC(9,6)) from sysibm.sysdummy1"

1
-----------
  25.555000

  1 record(s) selected.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question.  My original Column is Sample which consists of 36 characters which is 0103019780199999910006025555000 and I'm trying to extract the last 9 digits and divide it by 1000000 which gives me 25.555 and storing it in temp. I'm using this CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(0103019780199999910006025555000, 1, 36), 23, 9) AS DOUBLE)/1000000. Once I get 25.555 I used CAST(25.555 AS DEC(9,6))

Comment: I still get 25.555000.

Comment: I'm using DB2 AS400

Comment: I'm getting 25.554999 using this too!         select cast(CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(0103019780199999910006025555000, 1, 36), 23, 9) AS DOUBLE)/1000000 AS DEC(9,6)) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

Comment: Same result here (IBM i), but not with `values cast(cast(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(0103019780199999910006025555000, 1, 36), 23, 9) as dec(9))/ 1000000 as dec(9, 6))` or `values cast(cast(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(0103019780199999910006025555000, 1, 36), 23, 9) as decfloat)/ 1000000 as dec(9, 6))`. I don't know exactly why `values dec(25.555e0, 9, 6)` gives 25.554999 when `values char(25.555e0)`gives 2.5555E1

Comment: Thanks a lot! Replacing double with dec worked.

Answer (score 2):

Do not cast the enumerator to `DOUBLE`.
Cast it to `DEC (25)` to get `DEC (31, 6)` from `DEC (25) / INT` according to [Decimal arithmetic in SQL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=operators-decimal-arithmetic-in-sql) (look at the formula for `Division`).

```
VALUES 
-- CAST (CAST (SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING ('0103019780199999910006025555000', 1, 36), 23, 9) AS DOUBLE  ) / 1000000  AS DEC (9, 6))
   CAST (CAST (SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING ('0103019780199999910006025555000', 1, 36), 23, 9) AS DEC (25)) / 1000000  AS DEC (9, 6))
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Replacing double with dec worked.